# Executing custom script through non-interactive is different from executing through console

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, javascript, console

I have a private ethereum blockchain with a script, filename.js.

```
miner.stop();
debug.verbosity(4)
loadScript("path to FileStorage.js");
var DataStorageContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(FileOutput.contracts["FileContract.sol:D
ataStorage"].abi));
var f = 'QmaFDzPfZKwKchNNPBKKVHDz7msc6PTtkYjkWudyKnvF8B'  
var d = 'dc2e26b90098aef8457c24bde1ffd5fda15667cf98697fe0c2f77d6be3b6726d'
var fileStorage = DataStorageContract.new(f, d, { from: web3.eth.accounts[0], data: "0x" + File
Output.contracts["FileContract.sol:DataStorage"].bin, gas: '1000000'},  function (e, contract) 
{
    if(!e) {
        if(!contract.address) {
            console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHa
sh + " waiting to be mined...");
            console.log('Error1: ' + e);
        } else {
            console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address); console.log(contract);
            console.log('Error2: ' + e);
        }
        console.log('Error3: ' + e);
    }
    console.log('Error4: ' + e);
});
miner.start(8);
admin.sleep(10);
miner.stop();
```

When I attach to the blockchain

> geth --attach "path to ipc"

it returns a console. When I ran

> loadScript("path to filename.js")

I got an output

> Contract transaction send: TransactionHash:
>   0x92a875d52660c659ccf0e8fbb1b9d8be109f632db22b1c017 978cdee406cdf18
>   waiting to be mined... true
>
> Contract mined! Address:
>   0xbfb5b63dacbd32833919c54da763be85d55f26e3 [object Object]

However, when I run it non-interactive using

> geth --exec 'loadScript("path to filename.js")' attach "path to ipc"

I get an output

> Contract transaction send: TransactionHash:
>   0x5e3d9ccfcf3b19d25e8c1dcd662606de10418320270679d8e086e93f04630d1c
>   waiting to be mined...
>
> true

It does not show the "Contract Mined" section in the non-interactive. How do I correct this?

Comment: Maybe try printing out the error (`e`)?

Comment: Nope, I tried printing the error in multiple places, it did not print the "Contract mined" section.

Comment: In the case where it didn't print "waiting to be mined" and also didn't print "Contract mined!", what was the value of `e`? Or are you saying execution never entered that function at all?

Comment: It printed None for e. It did enter the function in the interactive mode, when I printed the values, it did print f and d from the contract.address.

Comment: What is `None`? Sounds like Python, but this is JavaScript, right? Was it the string `"None"` or something else? (If so, what type?) I'm confused about how you could enter neither `console.log` branch but also have a falsey value for `e`.

Comment: Sorry, that was null, not None. My bad. I have updated the modified code.

Comment: And what's the output of the updated code?

Comment: With the non-interactive, I get Error1: null, Error3: null, Error4: null. With the interactive, I get this followed by Error2: null, Error3: null, Error4: null at the end of the run.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to follow this without the full output. Can you please make sure that the code in your question matches the code that you're running and that the output is the actual, full output you're seeing? I'm going to bow out for now.